# does gcc support arm7ej-s core?

Tags: gcc, arm

I'm woking on building a ARM7EJ-S based application with arm-none-eabi-gcc. I'm doing this in two ways. 
  Method-1. Eclipse + CodeSourcery
  Method-2. Work under command line with CodeSourcery + makefile

in Method-1, I have to select a target processor, but there's no ARM7EJ-S in the selectable items.
in Method-2, I can specify the target processor with -march= instead of core name. However, since the core architecture for ARM7EJ-S is v5TEJ, which is not in the candidate list. But v5TE is available.

So I'm confused... 
Doesn't GCC support ARM7EJ-S core?? 
Anyboday who know this or have any experience on this, please help me! I will appreciate very much.

Comment: be careful to understand the difference between the core and the architecture.  there are multiple cores that share the same architecture.  And the compiler/tools may allow the core name to be specified because that may be the information you have.  The arm docs for the core specify the architecture the architecture docs define the instruction set.  the compiler/toolchain converts your code into instructions from the instruction set.  the architecture is the key.  focus on that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "J" letter in the core and arch name refers to *Jazelle*, a hardware acceleration feature for Java bytecode. Since this doesn't affect your C or C++ code at all, you can just use v5TE and stop worrying.